# How to use .lib files - node-gyp windows

Tags: node.js, windows, node-gyp, lib, tdlib

I have .lib static library - windows. How correctly include it to node-gyp project. I did it, but I caught `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol`. I think, I add library incorrectly. This libriary is tdlib (telegram database library).  Thank you for your help!

My binding.gyp file

```
{
    "targets": [
      {
        
        "target_name": "td_json",
        "sources": [ "lib.cc" ],
        "libraries": [
          "<(module_root_dir)/td/build/Release/tdjson.lib"
          ],
        "include_dirs": [
          "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include_dir\")"
          ],
        'dependencies': [
            "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
        ],
        "copies": [
            {
              "destination": "<(module_root_dir)/build/Release/",
              "files": [
                "<(module_root_dir)/td/build/Release/tdjson.dll" ]
            }
        ],
        "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ]
      }
    ]
  }
```